Best way to set up a development environment for an R package
I've uploaded an R package to CRAN and also have a corresponding GitHub repo for it. I plan to make quite a lot of changes to the package going forward but I want to test them in my R console first - how can I do this? Specifically, I'd like to be able to load the CRAN version and a development version in R together to compare. So for example library(package) and library(packageDev), but without the latter being publicly available.

devtools::load_all() vs library(package).

Avoid questions asking for the "best" way to do something. That's subjective and dependent on your specific needs. Are you already using devtools to develop your package? Or what exactly is your development setup?

The changer package can be used to automatically change the name of a package so that you can load two versions at once with different names.
